# Laravel How to skip elements if element is null in foreach loops?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I want to show latest posts in each category. If all category is not null, its OK, But if there are empty categories `Trying to get property of non-object` error. (I mean if category dosen't have any post)

So how can I pass thos categories post, when item returns null ?

Controller;

```
$categories=Category::with('posts')->latest()->get();
return view('frontend.home',compact('categories');
```

Blade;

```
@foreach($categories as $category)

<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="card text-white">
    <a href="#"> <img class="card-img"
       src="{{url('uploads/'.$category->posts->first()->featured_image)}}"  alt="Card image">                                             

      <div class="card-img-overlay">
      <h4 class="card-title">{{$category->category_name}}</h4>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

@endforeach
```

Any advice ?

Comment: use array_filter() to remove empty categories before foreach or in controller itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply check if there are any posts in every category in the foreach and put all the html in the if statement

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
    @if( count($category->posts) )
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="card text-white">
                <a href="#"> <img class="card-img" src="{{url('uploads/'.$category->posts->first()->featured_image)}}"  alt="Card image">                                             
          <div class="card-img-overlay">
              <h4 class="card-title">{{$category->category_name}}</h4>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

to show the posts for every category...

```
You can simply check if there are any posts in every category in the foreach and put all the html in the if statement

@foreach($categories as $category)
    @if( count($category->posts) )
        @foreach($category->posts as $post)
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="card text-white">
                  <a href="#"> <img class="card-img" src="{{url('uploads/'.$post->featured_image)}}"  alt="Card image">                                             
            <div class="card-img-overlay">
                <h4 class="card-title">{{$category->category_name}}</h4>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      @endforeach
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: its works as well but one post is disappear :/ why :?

Comment: because you show only the first() ... :)   you need to iterate the category->posts ...

Comment: I using this first, cause it gives me collection, I'm taking array with that